# Como faço para verificar o código de status da resposta http do servidor em java?

Tags: java, http-status

Bom dia, pessoal.

Gostaria de saber como faço em java para verificar se a resposta recebida do servidor foi com sucesso ou não.

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Qual código você tem até agora? poderia por favor postar ?

Comment: Nem comecei ainda, apenas queria saber qual metodo eh utilizade de alguma API do tipo HTTP em java. É assim, eu irei enviar uma request ao servidor, e queria saber apenas a resposta, se é 200, 404, 500 ou outra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua questão está muito ampla, pois a resposta pode ou não te servir de acordo com o que você quer fazer, que você deveria explicar melhor.

Entretanto, vou tentar te ajudar do mesmo jeito. Por exemplo:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Download {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection c1 = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://grepcode.com").openConnection();
        int code1 = c1.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(code1);

        HttpURLConnection c2 = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://grepcode.com/naoexiste").openConnection();
        int code2 = c2.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(code2);
    }
}
```

Este código estabelece duas conexões e mostra o código de status HTTP. A primeira mostrará 200 (ok) e a segunda mostrará 404 (página não encontrada). Use os status 2xx para sucesso e 4xx ou 5xx para erros, aonde erros 4xx provavelmente são erros seus e erros 5xx provavelmente são problemas no servidor.

Se a conexão não puder ser estabelecida, um `IOException` será lançado. No seu, código é importante que você teste por eles e saiba tratá-los adequadamente.

É possível fazer-se mudanças e personalizações no objeto `HttpURLConnection` **antes** de chamar o `getResponse()`. Tais mudanças seriam para definir *headers*, alterar o método HTTP (por exemplo, usar POST ao invés de GET), definir que você gostaria de efetuar upload, configurar caches, *proxies*, *timeouts*, etc. Veja [os javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) para ver quais métodos você poderia utilizar neste caso.

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi meu problema utilizando o WebResponse da seguinte forma:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.getDefault());
HtmlPage paginaResponse = (HtmlPage) client.getPage("http://www.website.com");

WebResponse response = paginaResponse.getWebResponse();

      if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {


         //codigo

      }
```

Resolvi fazer dessa forma, pois já estava utilizando o WebClient e o HtmlPage no método.