# Dúvida sobre ping em servidor e envio de e-mail

Tags: ping

Estou com uma necessidade de criar uma rotina que a cada minuto teste se o servidor da empresa está online e se não for possível envie um e-mail avisando o nome do servidor indisponível e o horário.

Outra questão, como caso caia a internet, a conexão ficará indisponível, sendo assim eu teria que ter esse programa rodando em outro local?

Já trabalhei a um bom tempo com Java, a um bom tempo mesmo. Contudo se tiverem algo free que possa utilizar, estou disposto a implementar.

Grato. God Bless All

Comment: Talvez sirva para te ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71387/132

Comment: Em qual linguaguem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução é desenvolver um script que faça requests num determinado tempo, de acordo com o tipo retorno envie o e-mail. Para facilitar, pode ser configurado como um *job* no Jenkins. 
É essencial que esteja num servidor separado de onde irá testar, óbvio que se estiver no mesmo local do servidor de teste, se este cair você nunca receberá o e-mail. O problema de rodar localmente é a dependência de internet. Digo, você pode garantir que haja internet localmente 24 horas durante todos os 7 dias da semana? Então, o ideal é o script estar num servidor separado.
Outra solução é utilizar os serviços disponíveis **gratuitamente** na internet, tais como: 
[New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) 
[Uptime Robot](https://uptimerobot.com/)

Apesar de possuerem algumas features pagas, atendem perfeitamente a exigência de algo básico.